# Look for a changed file inside pull request

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm trying to add a validation policy that checks if a changelog file has been changed or not inside a PR.

Currently I'm trying to manage by different ways, but no one finally working

for instance if I try to do it using git diff it's always throwing me an error:

`git diff --name-only changelog.md`

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'changelog.md': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git  [...] -- [...]'

How can I make this check?

I tried also with --exit-code with no success

Thank in advance

Comment: Git seems to think that `changelog.md` is not a valid file from where the command is being run.

Comment: First of all you should place a `--` before the `changelog.md`, like `git diff --name-only -- changelog.md`. This tells git that `changelog.md` is a path rather than a branch. This will result in your script detecting no changes, because there is no file `changelog.md` in the current directory, as @evolutionxbox already pointed out.

Comment: Are you sure the command you gave is the proper one? I would assume a "PR" to be a branch and you want to check, whether any one commit on this branch changes the mentioned file. For that purpose you need to call `git diff` with additional parameters.